# php generate image dynamically base on textbox text

Tags: php, jquery, textbox

I want to display an image or set of images next to a textbox base on the texts typed there.
eg.

```
If type "cat" it displays image "cat.jpg" or type "ca" it displays "car.jpg" and "cat.jpg"
```

I am trying this:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//do something here???
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
        $q=$_GET['q'];
        $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);

        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'mydb';
        $user = 'username';
        $pass = '';

        mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($db);
        $NameImage = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from `mydb`.`mytable` where `description` LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY `name` "); 
        $rowName = mysql_fetch_array($NameImage);


?>
    <label>Tag:</label>
    <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="20"/>  <img src = "myimagepath/<?php echo $rowName[0] ?>.jpg"  height="140">        
</body>
</html>
```

But the difficulty is I don't know how to get text value in textbox without submit (when user typing). And how to populate image dynamically based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first.php file write this :

```
<script src="js/jquerymin.js"></script>
<script>
function getImage(value)
{
    $.ajax({
                url: 'getImage.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'value' : value,
                },
                beforeSend : function() {                   
                },
                success : function(response) { 

                      $('.main-content').html(response);
                },
                error : function() {                                                
                },
                complete : function() {
                }

            });
}
</script>
<body>
 <label>Tag:</label>
         <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="20" onkeyup="getImage(this.value);"/>       

         <div class="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your getImage.php

```
<?php

        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'mydb';
        $user = 'username';
        $pass = '';

        mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($db);

        $val = $_POST['value'];
        $sql_img="SELECT `name` from `mydb`.`mytable` where `description` LIKE '%$val%' ORDER BY `name`";
        $result=mysql_query($sql_img, $con);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            echo "<img src='myimagepath/".$row[name]."'/>";
            echo "<br>"; 
        } 

    ?>
```

HTML5 give facility for auto suggestion:

```
<input type="text"  name="tag" id="tag" list="sometag" onchange="alert(this.value);" />
<datalist id="sometag">
   <select onchange="$('#tag').val(this.value)">
    <?php
        //select option list from data base
    ?>
   </select>
</datalist>
```

for reference see : http://devproconnections.com/html5/working-html5-web-forms-autocompletion-and-datalist-element

But important thing is onchange event of input box will occurs only when focus out from input and if text is change. It not look nice.

Comment: One thing to note: I just post answer as your question using mysql. But should not use mysql. Instead of use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Why is that so ? Btw, in my application, actually I can use suggestion when user type in, then they can click to choose suggestion text too, so can I use anything like "onchange" instead of "onkeyup" ?

Comment: I edited answer. But note that onchange event will not look nice on input box

Comment: Yeah, I know can populate suggestion by html5 support. I get options from DB, using this method: http://tutsforweb.blogspot.sg/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html. The problem is when I click the option suggested, the value in the textbox not recognized as "onchange" (may be we need to put something on document ready?). If I use "onclick" then I have to click to choose the option, then click on textbox again, which is not convenient.

Comment: Ok, I got the answer, I can do it by setInterval and put getImage inside that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need some Script as source of your image. Then you can Simply change the source of image via JavaScript as you past the Text to print as GET Parameter to this Script.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: Sry i think i didn't get your Question right. You try to display images which are already existing and the filenames are in your database? You just want something like a suggestion or do you want to create a image with the text out of the input field?